# Sitecore SXA Search Results Filter number of fields returned in SOLR response

Tags: sxa, sxa-search

I am using Sitecore 10.1 with SXA, I have a page that contains search results component and I have noticed that the query that is generated and run on SOLR is retrieving all the fields in the response.
Is there a way to override this behavior and return only the fields that will be displayed in search results component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do that out of the box. You would need to override `Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.Services.SearchService` in order to change the way how the query is generated. Right now we are using `Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.Models.ContentPage` as a query return type. It contains a few SXA specific fields and inherits from the Sitecore `Sitecore.ContentSearch.SearchTypes.SearchResultItem` class which contains a loooot of fields (as you notice it).

So technically it is possible but I strongly recommend not to do that as you will end up overriding a few classes while the Search Results component is using paging anyway (you are not getting all of the items and all of the fields at one time).